# How to block Java Thin client request till preloading of data in Ignite cluster is completed

Tags: java, ignite

We are running an ignite cluster with 3 nodes which pre-loads the data from 3rd party database (using custom cache store). when we try to connect to the cluster using java thin client and if the request reaches the cluster before data loading gets completed, we are getting unknown pair exception and some unstable behavior.

Is there anyway we can block the client request (TCP socket connection) till the data loading gets completed? 
I tried with different life cycle events (NODE_START_COMPLETED) but no luck.

Stack trace

```
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-845247802]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:707)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1757)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1716)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:798)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:67)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1773)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1761)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:573)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.putAll(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:627)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxAdapter.batchStoreCommit(IgniteTxAdapter.java:1507)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxLocalAdapter.userCommit(IgniteTxLocalAdapter.java:589)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.localFinish(GridNearTxLocal.java:3646)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxFinishFuture.doFinish(GridNearTxFinishFuture.java:475)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-845247802]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:394)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:344)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:698)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you add the exception that you get to the question?

Comment: Added trace for unknown pair exception

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to forbid thin clients to connect to a cluster using Ignite API at the moment. I created a JIRA ticket for this improvement: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12237

The unknown pair exception doesn't seem to be caused by thin clients connecting at a wrong time though. Usually it's caused by a missing `marshaller` directory in the work path.

Comment: We are preloading data from DB which is expected to create the marshaller directory. Since the client request is processed even before the record is loaded, we ended up with this error. This is also one of the reason for us to hold the client request till we complete our data loading